# how to find a function in windbg

Tags: windows, windbg

I'm using windbg to debug windows kernel files. The problem is that I know which function
to set break point but I don't know the module the function belongs. I use windows server
2019 and the module should be ntoskrnl from the import in IDA. I didn't find the module
in windbg somehow(maybe there is a alias). How do I know which module imports the
function or the address of the function?
The loaded modules are as follows

```
start             end                 module name
ffffaa98`27400000 ffffaa98`2778b000   win32kfull   (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\win32kfull.pdb\BD15EC0EDD344DABCC32F9C2E347B97B1\win32kfull.pdb
ffffaa98`27790000 ffffaa98`279ec000   win32kbase   (deferred)             
ffffaa98`279f0000 ffffaa98`27a38000   cdd        (deferred)             
ffffaa98`28300000 ffffaa98`2838b000   win32k     (deferred)             
fffff801`19c0e000 fffff801`19cab000   hal        (deferred)             
fffff801`19cac000 fffff801`1a71c000   nt         (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\ntkrnlmp.pdb\45C12C294F739481AC5E8E014C068FB61\ntkrnlmp.pdb
fffff801`1a800000 fffff801`1a80e000   kdcom      (deferred)             
fffff80f`e7c00000 fffff80f`e7c70000   FLTMGR     (deferred)             
fffff80f`e7c80000 fffff80f`e7d8a000   clipsp     (deferred)             
fffff80f`e7d90000 fffff80f`e7d9e000   cmimcext   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e7da0000 fffff80f`e7dac000   ntosext    (deferred)             
fffff80f`e7db0000 fffff80f`e7e83000   CI         (deferred)             
fffff80f`e7e90000 fffff80f`e7f48000   cng        (deferred)             
fffff80f`e7f50000 fffff80f`e8021000   Wdf01000   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8030000 fffff80f`e8043000   WDFLDR     (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8050000 fffff80f`e8060000   WppRecorder   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8070000 fffff80f`e807f000   SleepStudyHelper   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8080000 fffff80f`e80a4000   acpiex     (deferred)             
fffff80f`e80b0000 fffff80f`e8101000   mssecflt   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8110000 fffff80f`e812a000   SgrmAgent   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8130000 fffff80f`e81f8000   ACPI       (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8200000 fffff80f`e8220000   mcupdate_AuthenticAMD   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8230000 fffff80f`e8292000   msrpc      (deferred)             
fffff80f`e82a0000 fffff80f`e82cb000   ksecdd     (deferred)             
fffff80f`e82d0000 fffff80f`e82e1000   werkernel   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e82f0000 fffff80f`e835a000   CLFS       (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8360000 fffff80f`e8387000   tm         (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8390000 fffff80f`e83a8000   PSHED      (deferred)             
fffff80f`e83b0000 fffff80f`e83bb000   BOOTVID    (deferred)             
fffff80f`e83c0000 fffff80f`e83cc000   WMILIB     (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8400000 fffff80f`e8443000   intelpep   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8450000 fffff80f`e845b000   WindowsTrustedRTProxy   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8460000 fffff80f`e8474000   pcw        (deferred)             
fffff80f`e84a0000 fffff80f`e85f3000   NDIS       (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8600000 fffff80f`e8695000   NETIO      (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\netio.pdb\C34301C2DC7F81959A5EF6C03D4BA3871\netio.pdb
fffff80f`e86a0000 fffff80f`e86ab000   msisadrv   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e86b0000 fffff80f`e86c2000   vdrvroot   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e86d0000 fffff80f`e873b000   pci        (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8740000 fffff80f`e876e000   pdc        (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8770000 fffff80f`e8789000   CEA        (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8790000 fffff80f`e87bf000   partmgr    (deferred)             
fffff80f`e87c0000 fffff80f`e87cb000   intelide   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e87d0000 fffff80f`e87e3000   PCIIDEX    (deferred)             
fffff80f`e87f0000 fffff80f`e8894000   spaceport   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e88a0000 fffff80f`e88b9000   volmgr     (deferred)             
fffff80f`e88c0000 fffff80f`e8923000   volmgrx    (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8930000 fffff80f`e894f000   mountmgr   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8950000 fffff80f`e895d000   atapi      (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8960000 fffff80f`e8996000   ataport    (deferred)             
fffff80f`e89a0000 fffff80f`e89bc000   EhStorClass   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e89c0000 fffff80f`e89fe000   Wof        (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8a00000 fffff80f`e8a15000   dfsrro     (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8a20000 fffff80f`e8a92000   WdFilter   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8aa0000 fffff80f`e8b0d000   volsnap    (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8b10000 fffff80f`e8b7f000   CLASSPNP   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8b80000 fffff80f`e8b95000   filecrypt   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8ba0000 fffff80f`e8bb6000   WindowsTrustedRT   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8bc0000 fffff80f`e8bd4000   dfs        (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8be0000 fffff80f`e8bea000   Null       (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8c20000 fffff80f`e8c4e000   cdrom      (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8c50000 fffff80f`e8c5e000   tbs        (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8c60000 fffff80f`e8eed000   Ntfs       (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8ef0000 fffff80f`e8f48000   VBoxGuest   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8f50000 fffff80f`e8f5d000   Fs_Rec     (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8f60000 fffff80f`e8f92000   ksecpkg    (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8fa0000 fffff80f`e8fbc000   disk       (deferred)             
fffff80f`e8fc0000 fffff80f`e8fdc000   crashdmp   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9000000 fffff80f`e9078000   fwpkclnt   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9080000 fffff80f`e90b0000   wfplwfs    (deferred)             
fffff80f`e90c0000 fffff80f`e90cb000   volume     (deferred)             
fffff80f`e90d0000 fffff80f`e90f5000   mup        (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9120000 fffff80f`e93fa000   tcpip      (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9a00000 fffff80f`e9a51000   netbt      (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9a60000 fffff80f`e9a73000   afunix     (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9a80000 fffff80f`e9b26000   afd        (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9b30000 fffff80f`e9b5b000   pacer      (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9b60000 fffff80f`e9b74000   netbios    (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9bc0000 fffff80f`e9efb000   dxgkrnl    (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9f00000 fffff80f`e9f16000   watchdog   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9f20000 fffff80f`e9f36000   BasicDisplay   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9f40000 fffff80f`e9f51000   BasicRender   (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9f60000 fffff80f`e9f7c000   Npfs       (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9f80000 fffff80f`e9f91000   Msfs       (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9fa0000 fffff80f`e9fc7000   tdx        (deferred)             
fffff80f`e9fd0000 fffff80f`e9fe0000   TDI        (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea000000 fffff80f`ea04e000   ahcache    (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea050000 fffff80f`ea061000   CompositeBus   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea070000 fffff80f`ea07d000   kdnic      (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea080000 fffff80f`ea095000   umbus      (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea0a0000 fffff80f`ea0c1000   i8042prt   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea0d0000 fffff80f`ea0e3000   kbdclass   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea0f0000 fffff80f`ea13a000   VBoxMouse   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea140000 fffff80f`ea153000   mouclass   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea160000 fffff80f`ea1d6000   VBoxWddm   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea1e0000 fffff80f`ea204080   E1G6032E   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea210000 fffff80f`ea21f000   usbohci    (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea220000 fffff80f`ea29b000   USBPORT    (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea2a0000 fffff80f`ea2af000   CmBatt     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea2b0000 fffff80f`ea2c0000   BATTC      (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea2d0000 fffff80f`ea30a000   amdppm     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea310000 fffff80f`ea31d000   NdisVirtualBus   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea320000 fffff80f`ea32c000   swenum     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea330000 fffff80f`ea3a5000   ks         (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea3b0000 fffff80f`ea3be000   rdpbus     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea3c0000 fffff80f`ea448000   usbhub     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea450000 fffff80f`ea45e000   USBD       (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea460000 fffff80f`ea47f000   cdfs       (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea490000 fffff80f`ea49f000   dump_dumpata   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea4b0000 fffff80f`ea4bd000   dump_atapi   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea4c0000 fffff80f`ea4d2000   hidusb     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea4e0000 fffff80f`ea51b000   HIDCLASS   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea520000 fffff80f`ea533000   HIDPARSE   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea540000 fffff80f`ea5c9000   mrxsmb     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea5d0000 fffff80f`ea616000   mrxsmb20   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea620000 fffff80f`ea66f000   srvnet     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea670000 fffff80f`ea735000   srv2       (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea740000 fffff80f`ea76b000   winquic    (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea770000 fffff80f`ea8aa000   HTTP       (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea8b0000 fffff80f`ea986000   peauth     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea990000 fffff80f`ea9a4000   tcpipreg   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea9b0000 fffff80f`ea9cc000   rassstp    (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea9d0000 fffff80f`ea9e8000   NDProxy    (deferred)             
fffff80f`ea9f0000 fffff80f`eaa17000   AgileVpn   (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaa20000 fffff80f`eaa41000   rasl2tp    (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaa50000 fffff80f`eaa70000   raspptp    (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaa80000 fffff80f`eaa9c000   raspppoe   (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaaa0000 fffff80f`eaab5000   rasgre     (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaac0000 fffff80f`eaacf000   ndistapi   (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaad0000 fffff80f`eab0b000   ndiswan    (deferred)             
fffff80f`eab10000 fffff80f`eab23000   condrv     (deferred)             
fffff80f`eab30000 fffff80f`eab3f000   mouhid     (deferred)             
fffff80f`eab40000 fffff80f`eab56000   monitor    (deferred)             
fffff80f`eab60000 fffff80f`eac38000   dxgmms2    (deferred)             
fffff80f`eac40000 fffff80f`eac69000   luafv      (deferred)             
fffff80f`eac70000 fffff80f`eac9d000   wcifs      (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaca0000 fffff80f`ead16000   cldflt     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ead20000 fffff80f`ead3b000   storqosflt   (deferred)             
fffff80f`ead40000 fffff80f`ead58000   lltdio     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ead60000 fffff80f`ead7a000   mslldp     (deferred)             
fffff80f`ead80000 fffff80f`ead9b000   rspndr     (deferred)             
fffff80f`eada0000 fffff80f`eadbc000   wanarp     (deferred)             
fffff80f`eadc0000 fffff80f`eade5000   bowser     (deferred)             
fffff80f`eae00000 fffff80f`eae7a000   VBoxSF     (deferred)             
fffff80f`eae80000 fffff80f`eaefa000   rdbss      (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaf00000 fffff80f`eaf12000   nsiproxy   (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaf20000 fffff80f`eaf2d000   npsvctrig   (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaf30000 fffff80f`eaf40000   mssmbios   (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaf50000 fffff80f`eaf7c000   dfsc       (deferred)             
fffff80f`eaf80000 fffff80f`eaf9a000   mpsdrv     (deferred)             
fffff80f`eafa0000 fffff80f`eafb4000   bam        (deferred)             
fffff80f`eafc0000 fffff80f`eafdb000   WdNisDrv   (deferred)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use windows server 2019 and the module should be ntoskrnl from the import in IDA. I didn't find the module in windbg somehow(maybe there is a alias).

That's the Windows' kernel binary, it's symbolic name is `nt`.

> How do I know which module imports the function or the address of the function?

There are multiple ways of doing this, but I think the easiest is probably:

1. reload all modules symbolic information.

For this you can use the [`.reload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-reload--reload-module-) command and especially the `/f` and `/s` switches. Be wary that it can take some time.

Side Note: When you list all modules (using [`lm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/lm--list-loaded-modules-)) you can see that they are marked as being "deferred":

```
0: kd> lm
start             end                 module name
ffffea92`71600000 ffffea92`718d3000   win32kbase   (deferred)
ffffea92`718e0000 ffffea92`71c95000   win32kfull   (deferred)
ffffea92`71ca0000 ffffea92`71ce9000   cdd        (deferred)
ffffea92`72200000 ffffea92`7229a000   win32k     (deferred)
fffff806`06200000 fffff806`06236000   wcifs      (deferred)
fffff806`06240000 fffff806`06254000   mmcss      (deferred)
fffff806`06260000 fffff806`062b6000   WUDFRd     (deferred)
fffff806`062c0000 fffff806`06341000   cldflt     (deferred)
...
```

This means the symbolic information is loaded only when needed ("lazy sombol loading"; e.g. when setting a breakpoint). If we want to find a symbol we really need that information to be loaded, thus we need `.reload /f /s` (or just `.reload /f`).

2. Search for the symbol.

Using the "examine symbol" command [`x`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/x--examine-symbols-). Notice you can use wildcards.

### Example

Let say you have the `NtCreateFile` API and you want to know which module is implementing it:

```
0: kd> .reload /f
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
......

0: kd> x *!NtCreateFile
fffff806`08e99260 nt!NtCreateFile (NtCreateFile)

0: kd> lmDvm nt
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff806`08800000 fffff806`09846000   nt         (pdb symbols)          g:\symbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\5D6312DA6921E3A4E7F938B88330B0771\ntkrnlmp.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: ntkrnlmp.exe
    Image path: ntkrnlmp.exe
    Image name: ntkrnlmp.exe
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Image was built with /Brepro flag.
    Timestamp:        73F1C0C4 (This is a reproducible build file hash, not a timestamp)
    CheckSum:         00A65799
    ImageSize:        01046000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
    Information from resource tables:
```

It's in the `nt` module (the kernel).

### About .reload

Most of the time, you wont need to reload the symbols for the whole kernel space, since theoretically only the kernel binary (nt) provides the APIs that will be called. You should just do `x` and then if you don't have a proper answer then try to reload the other modules symbolic information with `.reload /f`.